# Custom User Profile property

Tags: user-profile-property

If there is no data for the custom user profile properties will it not show up on edit profile page? If so please let me know if there is any code fix to show the property that has no data on the edit profile page.

Thanks,
Rakie

Comment: To confirm, if it has data it shows?

Comment: How are you creating the custom profile property?